# Linked Server unable to begin a distributed transaction - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am end user on `SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU7-GDR)`.

I am trying to execute a query of the following nature:

```
DECLARE @sqlcode VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlcode = 'proprietary sql code'
TRUNCATE TABLE [wundermahndb].[dbo].[Training]
INSERT INTO [wundermahndb].[dbo].[Training]
exec ( @sqlcode ) at OLAP
```

What I end up with is an error for:

```
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "OLAP" returned message "Unable to enlist in the transaction.".
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 243
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "OLAP" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

I then tried adding these two lines at the top of my query:

```
set XACT_ABORT on
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'OLAP', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
```

And got the following error:

```
Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_serveroption, Line 27 [Batch Start Line 0]
User does not have permission to perform this action.
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "OLAP" returned message "Unable to enlist in the transaction.".
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 243
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "OLAP" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

I have referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56397682/create-new-table-with-results-from-exec) but that solution is what I have tried above which is clearly not working.

I have also looked:

- [Unable to begin a distributed transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473508/unable-to-begin-a-distributed-transaction)
- [The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" was unable to begin a distributed transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407447/the-operation-could-not-be-performed-because-ole-db-provider-sqlncli10-for-lin)

How can I run this query?

(NOTE - I am using SSMS 2017)

**UPDATE**

If I remove `TRUNCATE TABLE...` and `INSERT INTO...`, and simply issue:

```
DECLARE @sqlcode VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlcode = 'proprietary sql code'
exec ( @sqlcode ) at OLAP
```

It runs normally and returns the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off `remote proc transaction promotion` [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-serveroption-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for the linked server:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'OLAP', 
                                @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', 
                                @optvalue=N'false'
```

So SQL Server doesn't attempt to start a distributed transaction with the remote server.

Comment: `Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_serveroption, Line 27 [Batch Start Line 0]
User does not have permission to perform this action.
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ORAD" returned message "Unable to enlist in the transaction.".
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 244
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ORAD" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.`

Assuming I don't have the proper permissions to do so?

Answer (score 0):

From SQL2019 to SQL2017 if you have create linked server for insert operation, then this error comes.

Error:
"Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "" was unable to begin a distributed transaction."

Then you need to enable MSDTC, to solve this issue.

Open com component settings.

Enable MSDTC where sql 2019 installed.
Refer this link for enable help:
[Unable to begin a distributed transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473508/unable-to-begin-a-distributed-transaction)

This should start working fine after distributed transaction enabled in com components.

It solved my problem.