INSERT INTO Temp table results from a Stored procedure LINKED server
I want to insert the results from a stored procedure in a linked server.  Here is sample of the SQL.
INSERT INTO #Temptable
EXEC LinkedServerName.DBName.dbo.spName '01/01/2024', '08/01/2024'

The error I am getting is this.

The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "linkedservername" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

If I ran the stored procedure alone it runs without any problem the issue is inserting the data.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59256006/linked-server-unable-to-begin-a-distributed-transaction-sql-server might be a better duplicate, you need to turn off transaction promotion for the linked server. You might also get lucky if you use OPENQUERY and execute through it
